# Insert_one no such method exists @ pymongo 3.7.2

Tags: python, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I´m pretty new learning Python and all the containing stuff.

I tried to make my first little steps, installing a MongoDB (working) and connecting to it.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pprint import pprint
from random import randint



client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client.test
collection = db.users

user = {"id": 1, "username": "Test"}

user_id = collection.insert_one(user).inserted_id
print(user_id)
```

This is the complete code.

pymongo Version: 3.7.2 checked with:

```
pip freeze | grep pymongo
Output: pymongo==3.7.2
```

Python Version: 3.7.1

If I try to execute my tiny script, the following error occurs:

```
'Collection' object is not callable. 
If you meant to call the 'insert_one' method on a 'Collection'
object it is 
failing because no such method exists.
```

Where is my Fault?

A little research showed that in pymongo v2 the ".insert_one" is ".insert", but the 3.7.2 version is installed so I should (and must) use the ".insert.one", not the ".insert"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

insert_one according with pymongo documentation exists, for server version >= 3.2...

the use is:

```
user = {'x': 1}
result = db.test.insert_one(user)
result.inserted_id
```

more complete explanation about insert_one:

```
>>> db.test.count_documents({'x': 1})
0
>>> result = db.test.insert_one({'x': 1})
>>> result.inserted_id
ObjectId('54f112defba522406c9cc208')
>>> db.test.find_one({'x': 1})
{u'x': 1, u'_id': ObjectId('54f112defba522406c9cc208')}
```

the following below, I executed and works fine:

```
# importing client mongo to make the connection
from pymongo import MongoClient

print("--- Exemplo pymongo Connection ---")

# Connection to MongoDB
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)

# Selection the Database
db = client.python

# Select the collection
collection = db.users

# Set up a document
user = {"id": 1, "username": "Test"}

# insert one document into selected document
result = collection.insert_one(user)

# Selection just one document from collection
#result = collection.find_one()

# removing the document inserted
collection.delete_one(user)

# print the inserted_id
print("inserted_id: ", result.inserted_id)
```

[Pymongo Documentation](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html)